# Google Data Studio Filter Logic and Syntax

Tags: google-data-studio

In Google Data Studio, I'm trying to create a filter that functions like this:

`if (pageTitle=="foo" && previousPath=="bar") || (pageTitle=="fubar") {...}`

But I'm not not seeing a way to do this.

I can make logic like this:

`if (pageTitle=="foo" || previousPath=="bar") && (pageTitle=="fubar") {...}`

or this

`if (pageTitle=="foo") && (previousPath=="bar" || pageTitle=="fubar")`

But none of this leads to what I want.

Adding more than one filter also seems to result in an `AND` logic with the two filters.

Am I missing something? Is this not possible? Do I need to be using some other feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will possibly need to create a calculated field using a case statement and then use the resulting dimension within DS
[image]

More info on case statements in the DS docs
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724?hl=en